# variable assign and check

Tags: php, function, variables, conditional-statements

Can Someone tell me what's wrong with this code

```
function someFunction($num=null) {
  return $num;
}
if ($name = someFunction('mystr') && $name ) {
 echo 'hello ';
}else {
  echo 'hi';
}
```

Why it is going in else condition and giving me notice of undefined variable $name

Edited: - if i do like this

```
if($name = someFunction() && $name ){
   echo 'hello';
} else {
   echo 'hi';
}
```

this time its also going on else condition as it should but it also not showing the error as i understand it, php just check my first condition $name = someFunction() and its fail then just else

but if i do as i do previously $name = someFunction('str') now $name is set so why notice of undefined variable

sorry for bad grammer

just want to know what is happening here.

Comment: what is the actual point of the function? doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: what you expect as output?

Comment: `$name = someFunction('mystr') && $name` What are you planning to achieve here? What __exactly__ is your condition supposed to be?

Comment: It's like doing `$var = ('mystr' && <undefined variable>)` which is the reason for the error you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because logical operators like `&&` have higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. You can read more about this here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

The line

```
if ($name = someFunction('mystr') && $name ) {
```

is being evaluated like this:

```
if ($name = (someFunction('mystr') && $name) ) {
```

where the expression in the inner brackets is evaluated first. Because `$name` has not been defined before this point, a notice is raised.

I *think* what you're trying to do is this:

```
if (($name = someFunction('mystr')) && $name ) {
```

where you assign the value **mystr** to `$name` and then also evaluate that it's ["truthy"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). But as pointed out in the comments, this is a bit of a strange approach. The following code would be equivalent:

```
$name = 'mystr';

if ($name) {
  ...
```

This feels a bit like a problem that's been cut down a bit too much in order to explain it, because it's not really clear *why* you're doing this.

Comment: You could also use `and` since assignment has a higher precedence

Comment: i just forget about precedence

Comment: Actually i was working on some thing few days ago and i completely forget what was the problem there but i think i was wrong  

but happy to know about that what was happening there

Answer (score 1):

you code output : hi becuase there is  $name  is in second is always null.

```
function someFunction($num=null) {
  return $num;
}
$name = someFunction('mystr');
if ($name && $name ) {
 echo 'hello ';
}else {
echo 'hi';
  }
```

output : mystr && mystr = 1 then output is hello

Comment: You could fix this simple bug like this: `if (($name = someFunction('mystr')) && $name ) { ....  }`- Exactly the same but shorter (Although this code is still pointless anyway, but perhaps the OP just simplified if for us) +1

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned anything to your variable $name and since it is an AND Condition, the first gets true but the second one doesn't so assign any value to your $name and add a condition for it to work.